# Want ajax multiple file upload on my button click event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Here is my .aspx page code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
        Width="400px" OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete" Mode="Auto" />
    <asp:Button ID="abc" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="$('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click');" OnClick="abc_Click" />
</form>
```

.aspx.cs code is

```
 protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName));
    }
    protected void abc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // need file upload on this click and also need to store some outer data in this click event
    }
```

**How can I achieve ajax multiple file upload on my own button click event as I need to upload multiple file and also other some data on this button click**

**I have placed control html and the .cs code which is working well and is uploading multiple images with event OnUploadComplete but I need to upload images on abc_Click event so that on single click I can upload images as well as I can save data too**

Comment: This questions seems like offtopic in it's present form. Please edit and add more details with explaining the code and what is the issue you face with the code. Also _define other some data_

Comment: @SagarV which other details you need. I have placed control html and the .cs code which is working well and is uploading multiple images with event OnUploadComplete but I need to upload images on abc_Click event so that on single click i can upload images as well as I can save data too

Answer (score 3):

You should really consider migrating the project to **ASP.NET MVC**. That would give you a lot of perks, when *sending different and multiple data types to your code-behind*. Then you can make a **ViewModel** which can hold a list of the pictures, alongside with the other information you need, and send all the information to your backend in one call.

Off course, I don't know if you are already experienced in MVC, but if not,
refer to this link for more knowledge:
https://www.asp.net/mvc

I hope that helped you a little, else let me know.

Comment: absolutely yes!

Comment: I am using asp.net with  c#

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to upload multiple files in Asp.Net.
You Should use following method
HTML:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" Width="500px" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
```

C# Event

```
using System;
using System.IO;

 protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName));
}
```

Or you can use JQuery to upload Multiple files like below.
Download JQuery.js and jQuery.MultiFile.js from JQuery [multiple-file-upload plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Download)

Html:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadJquery" runat="server" class="multi"/>

<asp:Button ID="btnJqueryMultipleFiles" runat="server" Text="Upload Files Using Jquery" onclick="btnJqueryMultipleFiles_Click"/>
</div>
```

C# Event

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection multipleFiles = Request.Files;
        for (int fileCount = 0; fileCount < multipleFiles.Count; fileCount++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = multipleFiles[fileCount];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0 )
            {
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + fileName);
                lblMessage.Text += fileName + "Saved <br>";
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: I want to use ajax control according to requirement

Comment: Yes you can use first solution i mentioned if does not works you can post here.

Comment: In question I had already told that it is working perfectly but how can i achive same on my own button click

Comment: You should use HttpFileCollection multipleFiles = Request.Files;
        for (int fileCount = 0; fileCount < multipleFiles.Count; fileCount++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = multipleFiles[fileCount];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0 )
            {
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + fileName);
                lblMessage.Text += fileName + "Saved <br>";
            }
        }

Comment: In this code you had not added Id for AjaxFileUpload1. This id is not necessary to get the Image name or which image we want to upload

Comment: '<asp:AjaxFileUpload onchange="$('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click');" runat="server" /> ' try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148406/discussion-between-ravikumar-and-xtremcool).

Answer (score 0):

So I assume all is working well except that you wish to trigger the upload when some other button (that is probably in other part of your HTML markup) You can simply add a button on the same page:

```
<input type="button" value="Custom Upload Button" 
    onClick="$('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click'); 
        return false;" />
```

Comment: You answer is rigth but how can i achieve like this <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkcheckout" OnClientClick="btnclickvalidation();$('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click'); return false;" runat="server" OnClick="lnkcheckout_Click">CHECKOUT</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: if return is false then how can I achieve my onclick event

Comment: the return false is just to stop the click event propagation. However, i assume you did understand the logic behind it all since you awarded it the bounty and answer.

Comment: as per the question you had given the proper answer so you are awarded with bounty and answer

Comment: I am sorry to unanswer your question because using your onclick event it is uploading the file but not calling my OnUploadComplete_click event. If 3 images are uploaded then 3 times it used to call OnUploadcomplete click. I want this because I had implemented some code which stores image name in database on OnUploadComplete_click event.