# Cookies viewstate are not maintaining in AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, cookies, viewstate

I have cookies and viewstate in below control .
This ajax Control is used to upload multiple file images.

```
protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {           
        int userid = 25;
        DAL_Cart objdalcart = new DAL_Cart();
        if (Viewstate["Imagestringname"] == null)
        {
            objdalcart.InsertTempImage(userid, ImageName, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            objdalcart.InsertTempImage(userid, ImageName, 0);
        }
        Response.Cookies["JewelleryUserCookiesUserId"].Value = Convert.ToString(userid);
        Response.Cookies["JewelleryUserCookiesUserId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Viewstate["Imagestringname"] = ImageName + ",";
    }
```

The issue is when I try to retrive view state value or Cookies value on different click event of button in same page I am not able to retrive the value

```
 protected void lnkcheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Request.Cookies["JewelleryUserCookiesUserId"] == null || Request.Cookies["JewelleryUserCookiesUserId"].Value == "")
            {
             }
    if (Viewstate["Imagestringname"] != null)
        {}
     }
```

**For both the case it is going in if condition. for viewstate I have placed Enableviewstate=true on master page .Any idea why?**

**Review**

[Want ajax multiple file upload on my button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788327/want-ajax-multiple-file-upload-on-my-button-click-event/44883845#44883845)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var c = new HttpCookie("JewelleryUserCookiesUserId");
c.Value =  Convert.ToString(userid);
c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

Response.Cookies.Add(c);
```

Just note: this is insecure. the client can manipualte the cookie...

Comment: And what wrong I had done?. I had done same as u had

Comment: And why not viewsatte I can handle?

Comment: I think you need to leave the viewstate Idea. why you need it ?

Comment: You can refer this link what I really wanted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788327/want-ajax-multiple-file-upload-on-my-button-click-event/44883845#44883845


 But as it was not possible I think to store image name in view state and on my click button I can stored that image in data base

Comment: the response on the  link is right. you need to move to MVC and stop fighting these problems. use JS or get/post/cookie.